# Reverse Geocoding Multiple Lon/Lat R

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, reverse-geocoding

Note: I do not have much experience with R. I hope this is not too over my head!

I am trying to reverse geocode a data set of US longitudes and latitudes to their zip codes.

Firstly, I would prefer something that is not limited by queries (like google maps API). If that's not possible, help with the following would be greatly appreciated.

I learned to reverse geocode individual coordinates using the function reverseGeoCode() found from the following blog [post](http://allthingsr.blogspot.de/2012/03/geocode-and-reverse-geocode-your-data.html). It works great, but I am trying to reverse geocode a list of coordinates.

```
#load in my data
dir()
tw.data <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
#organize coodinates
long <- tw.data[,7]
lat <- tw.data[,8]
coords <- cbind(long,lat)

#reverse geocoding
reverseGeoCode <- function(latlng) {
latlngStr <-  gsub(' ','%20', paste(latlng, collapse=","))#Collapse and Encode     URL Parameters
  library("RJSONIO") #Load Library
  #Open Connection
  connectStr <- paste('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&latlng=',latlngStr, sep="")
  con <- url(connectStr)
  data.json <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(con), collapse=""))
  close(con)
  #Flatten the received JSON
  data.json <- unlist(data.json)
  if(data.json["status"]=="OK")
    address <- data.json["results.formatted_address"]
  return (address)
}
addresses <- reverseGeoCode(coords)
addresses
```

Do I need to organize my coordinates differently? Is this function not even made to deal with multiple points?

Any help would be *greaaatly apprediated* :)

Comment: That API has already been wrapped by `ggmap::revgeocode`

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a `matrix` of coordinates. You can use `apply`:

```
#create some random coordinates
set.seed(3)
coords<-matrix(runif(10,0,45),ncol=2) 
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,]  7.561869 27.197732
#[2,] 36.338238  5.608505
#[3,] 17.322406 13.257042
#[4,] 14.748044 25.992446
#[5,] 27.094530 28.394067
apply(coords,1,reverseGeoCode)
#[1] "Wau, South Sudan"                                                 
#[2] "Unnamed Road, Dehamcha, Algeria"                                  
#[3] "Nguigmi, Niger"                                                   
#[4] "Mellit, Sudan"                                                    
#[5] "Al Farafra - Al Wahat, Al Farafrah, New Valley Governorate, Egypt"
```

If you instead have a `list` with the `lat` and `lon` components, you can use `mapply`:

```
coordlist<-list(lat=coords[,1],lon=coords[,2])
#$lat
#[1]  7.561869 36.338238 17.322406 14.748044 27.094530
#$lon
#[1] 27.197732  5.608505 13.257042 25.992446 28.39406
mapply(function(x,y) reverseGeoCode(c(x,y)),coordlist$lat,coordlist$lon)
#same output as above
```

As already been stated from the comments, the `revgeocode` function from the `ggmap` package does what your `reverseGeoCode` does.